# Concatenating Strings and Numbers in Python

Tags: python-2.7

How can you concatenate strings and numbers in python

```
vec1=["a","b","c"]
vec2=[1,2,3]
```

What I want is to combine the two vectors such that the following is the output:

```
vec3=["a1","b2","c3"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

`zip` takes a list of iterables, and binds together every n-th element of each iterable into a new list.  Here's how `zip` would handle `vec1` and `vec2`:

```
>>> zip(vec1, vec2)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

So now you have a list of tuples, each containing a matched pair from both `vec1` and `vec2`;  all you need to do next is process your elements in order, and combine them into a single string.  This can be concisely achieved with a list comprehension:

```
vec3 = [a+str(b) for a, b in zip(vec1, vec2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
['{}{}'.format(*x) for x in zip(vec1, vec2)]
```